# Normal Map Node - Can't See A Difference In Render

Tags: texturing, materials, normal-map

I'm very new to Blender and I am trying to add a concrete normal map to a tower, however while it is visible on the material preview, it doesn't show on the object:

[image: Screenshot 1]

In this image you can see the preview material render as well as my nodes.

The render looks like so:

[image: Screenshot 2]

As you can see, the render doesn't look great - there are visible lines that I assume are needing smoothing, but as you can see my concern is that the bump map is not visible.

Why is this, and how can I get this normal map/texture working?

Comment: Normal Map should be set as "Non-color" color-space.

Comment: Lighting might be wrong for showing off material correctly. In addition to stated in the comment above make sure the object is unwrapped or if texture is tileable use procedural texture coordinates (e.g. Object) if you are fine with resulting output in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the mapping nodes in the wrong place. The image texture should be connected to the normal map node, the mapping node should be connected to the vector input of the image texture.

To keep the two image textures aligned, connect them to the same mapping node.

You should also change the colour space for a normal map to Non-Colour.

Note that the mapping node looks different in 2.81

[image: example node tree]